# Concatenate sub-cell items of a cell array avoiding for loop

Tags: matlab

I have a cell matrix c

```
a = {{'a'} {'aa','aaa','aaaa'}}
b = {{'b'} {'bb','bbb','bbbb'}}
c{1} = a ;
c{2} = b ;

c =

    {1x2 cell}    {1x2 cell}
```

I want to concatenate the sub-cells of c and store them in cell matrix d. More specifically, I want
`d{i} = [c{i}{1} c{i}{2}];` Can we do it without for loop taking advantage of build in Matlab functions like `cellfun`?

Thank you.

Comment: After some more tries I found it, `e = cellfun(@(x) [x{:}],s3d,'UniformOutput', false);` I leave the post enable in case someone wants to answer with an alternative way. Sorry, for the disturbunce and impatience.

Comment: @Troth your own solution seems to be the best, post it as answer, so the problem is solved and can be found by future readers.